# How to submit a form and then redirect to a personalized thank you page?

Tags: javascript, submit

```
        $("#new_note").submit();
    window.location.href='./thankyou.php?usr_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['pid'>';
```

Hi, this is a simple code for submitting a form and then redirect to a thank you page. It actually does the redirecting part but the form is not submitted

I guess it redirects before the submit is completed, how can it be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not redirect via JavaScript but make the page you submit your form to redirect to the "thanks" page.

Answer (score 0):

As @ThiefMaster says, you should redirect on the server side.

Otherwise, use the callback of the `submit` function. It makes sure the submit is performed.

```
$('#new_note').submit(function() {
    window.location.href = // your code
})
```

Comment: I want to redirect to a thank you page only if a get a specific answer, thats why i need to use javascript. I tried your solution but i didnt work for me, :( Thank you

Comment: You can do that using server-side too. Also, what didn't work? Have you debugged?

Comment: I was debugging right now, it does nothing when i press the submit button. Also, how can i redirect on server-side?. Im a total newbie, im sorry

Comment: Server-side depends on your technology. In PHP, you can use `header('Location: ' . $newlink)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with php but cant you redirect the page from the submit handler itself, after the process completed?  or use jquery load and and do the redirect from on load complete.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, wrap the redirection call in a jQuery's `.submit()` callback function.

Use the `window.location.replace(URL)` which is similar to a page redirect action.